# View array or one record in rails view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

In my method via some calculations a get data, then i need to view it in view, but if write

`@ar.each do |a|`

when i have only one record i get error, also when i have one error each is bad idea. So how to do this this?

So i have such code in method:

```
non_original = []
@articles.each do |a|
  non_original << get_non_tecdoc("LA44", 1, "KNECHT")
end
@non_original = non_original
```

get_non_tecdoc returns object, or nothing...

So in view i have:

```
-@non_original.each do |no|
      =no.brand
      =no.description
      =no.price
      =no.quantity
```

But what to do if @non_original  has one record, then @non_original.each gives error. So how to do check in view? If @non_original has one record, than simple @non_original.brand etc, but if more than one, than use each loop?

Comment: The way you have it written now, `@non_original` should always be an array, since your code only appends to it. You might also want a check around `get_non_tecdoc` to prevent it from inserting a `nil` into `@non_original` (e.g., `x = get_non_tecdoc(...); @non_original << x if x`).

Comment: @jmdeldin yes, it it array, but in view there are different ways of displaying array with one or more records... as in yours code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<%= debug @ar %>
```

This will give you a nice YAML format to look at in your view (assuming ERB).

**EDIT**: I believe this is what you want, since you're not interested in debugging.

In your controller, use the splat operator to convert a singleton element to an array (it doesn't modify arrays):

```
@ar = *@ar
```

Then `@ar.each` will work as expected in your view.

Alternatively, you could check in your view:

```
<% if @ar.is_a?(Array) %>
  <% @ar.each ... %>
<% else %>
  <%= @ar %>
<% end%>
```

Answer (score 3):

This will work with @ar as a single value as well as an array:

```
Array(@ar).each do |a|
  p a
end
```

This `Array` is a method on [Kernel](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-Array).

Comment: according to my logic i first find using AR, then via ruby instruments i prepare my data...So i could have in this variable one or more records, so how then view it in rails view? i don't need debug, but answer!

Comment: After `Array(@ar)`, just treat it like it is an Array, because it is one.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with an array with only one, or zero, elements. `each` will handle it.

Comment: but also will haml understand Array(@ar).each do |a| ? No i see that no

Comment: or how to write in view and controller?

Comment: @PavelBY: If `@ar` is a single element (not an array), you can just convert it with the splat operator. (I have an example in my answer below.)

Comment: still i get undefined method `each'

Comment: @PavelBY: Please update your question with more code. You seem to be in a hurry with the expectation everyone understands your problem clearly. This is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try using @ar.inspect and output it to the console to see the instance variables contents.

Comment: how view it? i could have one or more records in var! according to my logic i first find using AR, then via ruby instruments i prepare my data...So i could have in this variable one or more records, so how then view it in rails view? i don't need debug, but answer!

Comment: Check out [Rails Guides for Debugging](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#to_yaml) for more information on how to do it. I would use inspect or to_yaml method.

Comment: you don't get in problem... debug is another question.

Answer (score 0):

As long as @ar is an array you should not get a error. If you are returning one record change it to an array with one record.

If you are using [active record query interface](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#retrieving-multiple-objects) like the "where" clause; it will return an array with 0 or more active_record objects. If you use find it will return one instance of an active_record object.

So if your method that queries is using the active record where clause @ar should always return an array.

Answer (score -1):

Please try this:

```
Tablename.find_by_table_id
```

Example:

if account_id is 10 then, take following example,

```
@getResults = Account.find_by_account_id(10)
```

It will gives single record.
we can get values using @getResults.id,@getResults.name ....like wise.

Comment: according to my logic i first find using AR, then via ruby instruments i prepare my data...So i could have in this variable one or more records, so how then view it in rails view? i don't need debug, but answer!